# Ubuntu command line to replace replace single quotes ( ' ) with double quotes (")

Tags: ubuntu, sed

I’ve recently downloaded a photo album website template and I want to make it easy for my non-tech savvy life mate to add photos to.

It uses an XML file which requires editing each time photos are added and the update script I’ve written is almost complete, just needs to have all it’s single quotes (`'`) changed to double quotes (`"`).

I’ve found and played with `sed "s/\"/'/g"` to no avail, receiving an “unterminated quote error.” Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your command works perfectly well (as it should) in Ubuntu 15.04 and `bash` or `sh` as the shell. Have you extracted the command from a different context? As Michael Kjörling illustrates in his answer `sed` is more complicated than you need.

Answer (score 4):

You need a single backslash quoted quote, outside the single quotes:

```
sed 's/"/'\''/g'
```

When strings are juxtaposed they become one string. So you can quote parts differently, with "" or '' or \.

Comment: You don't really need to quote the `sed` parameter, provided there are no blanks or characters which the shell will expand: both `sed s/\"/\'/g` and the author's original string are neater.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `tr` to `tr`anslate from one character set to another. (Note: this is character set as in "a set of characters", not as in "a character encoding and its associated glyphs" such as ISO-8859-1.) You almost certainly don't need to use `sed` and regular expressions for this.

Your question is somewhat unclear as to which direction you want to go in because the `sed` command would do the opposite of what you say your aim is, but to translate from `'` to `"`, you can use (avoiding here [useless use of `cat`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_%28Unix%29#Useless_use_of_cat)):

```
tr \' \" <inputfile >outputfile
```

To translate from `"` to `'`, instead use:

```
tr \" \' <inputfile >outputfile
```

Note that the backslashes are important, as they protect the quotes from being interpreted specially by the shell. By the time `tr` sees the parameters, the backslashes will have been stripped away.

Be careful to not blindly rewrite the entire XML file; that seems likely to cause undesirable behavior.